# could a NFS volume export to VMWARE ESX used for Windows 2008 cluster?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esx, nfs, cluster, iscsi

Linux NFS export to VMWare ESX. Could this be used as shared storage for two Windows Virtual machines inside the ESX? "cluster in a box"

"Windows 2008 R2 needs support for SCSI-3 persistent reservations"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MS clustering needs to do scsci reservations and that's not supported by NFS.

Answer (score 1):

Under linux its a fast moving target, but some iscsi implementations support it:
http://scst.sourceforge.net/comparison.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you'll take a look at the following [document](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r40/vsp_40_mscs.pdf).